# Twisted task.LoopingCall : Unhandled error in Deferred:

Tags: python, twisted

My Code

```
from twisted.internet import task, reactor

def stuff():
    print('Hello, world!')

scheduler = task.LoopingCall(stuff())
scheduler.start(10)
reactor.run()
```

This is the Error I am getting

> Hello, world! Unhandled error in Deferred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Usama
> fiaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py",
> line 1315, in run
> self.mainLoop()   File "C:\Users\Usama fiaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py",
> line 1325, in mainLoop
> reactorBaseSelf.runUntilCurrent()   File "C:\Users\Usama fiaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py",
> line 991, in runUntilCurrent
> call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)   File "C:\Users\Usama fiaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\task.py",
> line 251, in **call**
> d = maybeDeferred(self.f, *self.a, **self.kw)
> ---  ---   File "C:\Users\Usama fiaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py",
> line 190, in maybeDeferred
> result = f(*args, **kwargs) builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

Per [the API documentation](https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/stable/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html), `LoopingCall.__init__` accepts a callable parameter `f` as its first argument.

In your example:

```
from twisted.internet import task, reactor

def stuff():
    print('Hello, world!')

scheduler = task.LoopingCall(stuff())
scheduler.start(10)
reactor.run()
```

the value being passed for `f` is the result of evaluating `stuff()` - in other words, it is the return value of the `stuff` function.  `stuff` implicitly returns `None` so your `LoopingCall` construction is equivalent to:

```
scheduler = task.LoopingCall(stuff())
```

Then, when you start the loop with `LoopingCall.start` you don't attach any error handlers.  When `LoopingCall` tries to call `None` an exception is raised.  Since there are no error handlers attached, the exception is reported as an "Unhandled error in Deferred" and logged for you.

If you want the `LoopingCall` to call `stuff` at the defined interval, pass `stuff` to it (instead of `None`).  If you want to deal with errors in your loop, attach an error handler to the `Deferred` returned by `LoopingCall.start`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove parentheses **()** to pass a function as a callback

```
def stuff():
    print('Hello, world!')

scheduler = task.LoopingCall(stuff)  # this is a callback
```

In this way, you just call the function and pass the `None` return value

```
scheduler = task.LoopingCall(stuff())  # this is a function call
```